# How to skip if element does not exist in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the restaurant names of a food delivery website, and the xpaths are randomly numerical.
Not all the numbers exist, so when it tries a certain number for x, the error appears. This is some of my input:

```
    restaurantname = ['//li[{}]/a/div[2]/h4'.format(x) for x in range(1, 999)]
    for restaurant in restaurantname[:999]:
        title = driver.find_element_by_xpath(restaurant).text
        print(title)
        print('*'*5)
```

This is the output in my terminal after I run the python file:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[157]/a/div[2]/h4"}
```

How do I make it simply skip if there is "no such element?"

Comment: Try to catch the error with try except block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should surround your `find_element_by_xpath()` and print statements with a [try/except](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/error-handling/python-try-and-except) block. This will allow you to handle the error with the keyword `pass`, which means "do nothing."

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I played around with the try/except and it worked!

Comment: Hi @MimiChung if you find this answers your question you should except it!

Comment: @MosheSlavin what do you mean except it

Comment: @MimiChung great to hear!